# how to pass index to sibling div/tag

Tags: vuejs2

I'm developing a mobile app using phonegap, vuejs2 and onsenui. I installed vue2-touch-events plugin for touch events. In this app i'm rendering some data using v-for. Here is the div.

```
<v-ons-list-item class="swipeArea"
 v-for="(list, index) in todoLists"
 v-bind:key="list.todo"
 v-if="!list.completed"
 v-touch:swipe.left="deleteLisItem(index)"
 v-touch:swipe.right="doneLisItem(index)"
 v-touch:longtap="deleteOrDone(index)" tappable>
    <label class="center">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ list.todo }}
    </label>
</v-ons-list-item>
```

And then when user longtap a list there will be a pop with 3 button. Done, Delete and cancel. When user tap done, the item will be mark as done, if click delete, the item will be deleted and click cancel will cancel the event. Here is the div

```
<div v-if="doneOrDelete" id="doneOrDelete">
    <div class="action-sheet-mask"></div>
    <div class="action-sheet">
        <button class="action-sheet-button" @click="doneLisItem">Done</button>
        <button class="action-sheet-button action-sheet-button--destructive" @click="deleteLisItem">Delete</button>
        <button class="action-sheet-button" @click="doneOrDelete=false">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now all i have to do is pass the index to the method. Can anyone help me how pass the index? TIA

Comment: What you mean by the index ? And the index of what ?

Comment: @Plotisateur I meant the key from v-for="(list, index) in todoLists". I want to pass this key (index) to popup div.

Comment: What's your build? I can't get your example code to work

Comment: @samayo my phonegap version is 7.1.1, vuejs 2 and onsenui v-2. And i'm using vue2-touch-events plugin for touch events.

Comment: Hmm.. that's a long list. Anyway, you can just use a temporary hack like v-show="popupData = index || true" and create a var called `popupData`

Comment: @samayo thanks for your reply. I got a better solution. https://jsfiddle.net/yb4os541/1/ It didn't solve my problem totally. But i' almost close to the answer.

Comment: How didn't it solve it?

Comment: @samayo sorry .. it did solve my problem.

Comment: @samayo post it as answer, that i can mark as answer.

Comment: Its okay, you can answer and accept it, It was just a simple solution, thanks anyway